# Haskell - Sort strings inside a tuple in alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, haskell, tuples

I have a list containing tuples that I would like to sort so that the *values* they contain appear in alphabetical order. I've toyed around with the Data.List-sorting but have only managed to sort the list, not the values of the tuples.

In essence, is there any way to turn a list of

```
[("foo","bar"),("stack","overflow"),("help","please")]
```

into a list

```
[("bar","foo"),("overflow","stack"),("help","please")]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple can only be either ordered or in inverse-order, because it always has exactly two elements, so these are the only permutations. Hence you simply need to check which is the case, and if necessary flip the tuple once.

```
sortTuple :: Ord a => (a,a) -> (a,a)
sortTuple (x,y)
  | x>y        = ...
  | otherwise  = ...
```

This question has nothing to do with lists, since you merely apply the operation independently to each element

```
sortTuplesInList :: Ord a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
sortTuplesInList = map sortTuple
```

Comment: Thank you, the map keyword was what I was looking for, our tutor hasn't gone over it yet in our Haskell course.

Comment: [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) isn't a keyword, it's a function.

Answer (score 2):

While tuples can vary in length (I think up to 64 elements), the wrapper list must be homogenous (i.e. all tuple elements will have the same length). This makes using something like list comprehension easy:

```
import Data.List

let sortedPairs = [(x,y) | [x,y] <- tmp]
  where tmp = [sort [x,y] | (x,y) <- [("m","l"),("p","q"),("s","r")]]
```

You can adjust the size of the tuples (and variables in the pattern matching) to fit your domain.

Hope this helps.